# Why do StackTrace' instance methods not work whereas StackTrace does?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

```
Console.WriteLine(Environment.StackTrace); //=> ... at LoggerClass.Main() C:\Projects\Logger\Logger\Logger.cs:line 164 ...

StackTrace stackTrace = new StackTrace();    
Console.WriteLine(stackTrace.GetFrame(0).GetMethod().Name);      //=> Main()
Console.WriteLine(stackTrace.GetFrame(0).GetFileName());         //=> ""
Console.WriteLine(stackTrace.GetFrame(0).GetFileLineNumber());   //=> 0
Console.WriteLine(stackTrace.GetFrame(0).GetFileColumnNumber()); //=> 0
```

The StackTrace returns all the information I need. The calling function `Main`, and the filepath and linenumber to this function, `C:\Projects\Logger\Logger\Logger.cs:line 164.`

However, while StrackTrace' `GetMethod` method does get the calling method's name, `GetFileName` returns an empty string, and `GetFileLineNumber` and `GetFileColumnNumber` both return 0.

Why is the stack trace working but the instance methods of StackTrace are dropping the ball completely?

Answer (score 2):

The constructor you're using is *explicitly* documented that way (emphasis mine):

> The StackTrace is created with the caller's current thread, and **does not contain file name, line number, or column information**.

If you want to get more information, use `new StackTrace(true)` which will capture source information. See the [documentation for all constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stacktrace.-ctor?view=net-6.0) for more details.